# Arrays to Linked Lists

Tags: c

This is in C.

I have to take the information from a command line (ex. ./command # # #)then run the information through a command and then print the subsequent information.

```
int *numbers = malloc(sizeof(argc)*sizeof(int));
int i = 0;
while (i<argc) {
    numbers[i] = atoi(argv[i+1]);
    i++;
   }

Node *a = arrayToList(numbers,sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(int));
Node *b = mapList(decrement,a);
displayList(b);

return 0;
```

It is meant to return values that are one less, but I am struggling to have the numbers read into the original array.

Any ideas?

Comment: the `numbers` pointer doesn't point to anything. You should either have it point to a `malloc`'d array ( but don't forget to `free` it!)  or you can use something like `int numbers[N]`  and avoid heap allocations if you know `N` ahead of time

Comment: I see one problem in your code. You are accessing `argv` more than you should. Use `while ( i < argc-1)`. Beyond that, I can't suggest anything useful without seeing more of your code.

Comment: If you have problem with reading, start with reading. You have many problem in this code. E.g. Uninitialized `numbers`, reading beyond end of `argv`, with such declaration of `numbers` `sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(int)` probably doesn't work like you expect. Rest is undeclared. So it's hard to tell what happens.

Comment: @AlejandroLucena is this the correct way to use malloc in this case? With this I still receive a Segmentation Fault

Comment: @yup, for your recent edit of `int *numbers = malloc(sizeof(argc))`, notice what you are doing. `argc` is an int, so sizeof(`argc`) only gives 4. What you'd want is to say something like `int* numbers = malloc(N * sizeof(int))`; where N is the amount of elements you would like. Which in this case, is simply `argc`. You could also just say `int numbers[argc];`

Comment: Or the more idiomatic `int *numbers = malloc(N * sizeof(*numbers));` to avoid the need to remember the type of `numbers`, minus one `*`, every time you need to call `malloc` or a related allocation function.

Comment: int numbers[argc] will not work. The expression must be a constant

Comment: @ChronoKitsune @AlejandroLucena; I have the code as shown above, but I am still receiving a segmentationfault, is there a problem with my loop?

Comment: @yup, you're still confusing the operation. `argc` already tells you how many elements you want. `sizeof(argc)` will tell you the sizeof an int.. which is most likely just going to be 4. What you want is `argc` itself

Comment: @IRocks Are you aware of [variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)?

Answer (score 2):

The first part of the code should be

```
if ( argc < 2 )
    exit( 1 );     // need at least one arg after the command name

int numbers[argc-1];
for ( int i = 1; i < argc; i++ )
    numbers[i-1] = atoi(argv[i]);
```

You need to allocate space for the `int`s, and then process the args from `1` to `argc-1`.

Comment: Thank you! But could you explain why you choose numbers[i-1] and argv[i] vs numbers[i] and argv[i+1]

Comment: The loop checks `i < argc`. When `i` is equal to `argc-1`, the index `i+1` is off the end of the `argv` array. Or at least it's past the last number. The specification says that `argv[argc]` is a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 1):

#### A visual to remedy any possible confusion

You seem to be getting slightly confused by the fact that array indices always start at 0, and counts always start at 1:

```
      index    count    value of argv[i]
    (argc-1)  (argc)

argv[    0]       1     "./my_program"
argv[    1]       2     "4"
argv[    2]       3     "8"
.
.
argv[N - 3]   N - 2     "128"
argv[N - 2]   N - 1     "256"
argv[N - 1]       N     "512"
argv[N    ]             NULL
```

If you aren't confused, I apologize, but I hope that helps to clear things up.

#### The allocation of the `numbers` array

Your code suggests you only want the command line arguments, so you'll want elements 1 to `argc` (exclusive) of the `argv` array:

```
1 <= i < argc                (mathematically)
for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i)   (equivalent C code)
```

As a result, you'll need to subtract 1 from `argc` and use that value as the count of elements in your array:

```
int count = argc - 1;

/*
 * int numbers[count];
 *
 * would work too if your compiler supports variable-length arrays (VLAs).
 *
 * That means you don't need to call `free(numbers);` at the end,
 * but it also means you may run out of stack space if a lot of
 * arguments are passed. Sometimes `malloc` is just a better option.
 */
int *numbers = malloc(count * sizeof(*numbers));
```

#### The read loop

Then your loop will look like the following:

```
for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i)
    numbers[i - 1] = atoi(argv[i]);
```

If you're confused, remember that you're storing `argv[3]` as a number into `numbers[2]`. 3-1=2, right? In other words, the index for `numbers` is `i - 1`, where `i` is the index for `argv`.  If you're wondering why I didn't use

```
for (i = 0; i < argc - 1; ++i)
    numbers[i] = atoi(argv[i + 1]);
```

it's because other than the increment operation that is the same in both loops, there is only one operation (subtraction) instead of two operations (subtraction and addition).

#### After the read loop

After that loop, you can just loop from 0 to `count` (`0 <= i < count`) any time you need to access your values in the `numbers` array, pass `count` to functions that need to know how many items are in the array, etc.:

```
/* Print all the numbers in the array to verify they were read correctly. */
printf("Numbers:");
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    printf(" %d", numbers[i]);
printf("\n");

Node *a = arrayToList(numbers, count);
```

Don't forget to `free(numbers);` before your program exits if you used `malloc`.

#### In case you were wondering…

And if you're wondering why you'd pass `count`, well, I'd first ask you why wouldn't you? Which is more readable: `sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(int)` or `count`?

More importantly, the `sizeof` approach simply will not work if you used `malloc` because `numbers` is a pointer and has no size information other than the size of the `int *` type, unlike an array that has information about its size. See [Arrays and Pointers on the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cgi-bin/faqcat.cgi?sec=aryptr) for more than enough information to explain the phrases "pointers are not arrays" and "arrays are not pointers".